# Change of basis (vector space $\mathbb{R}_{2n}[X]$)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with this exercise :

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ ($a \neq b$).
Show that $\{(X - a)^{k}\}_{0 \leq k \leq 2n}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_{2n}[X]$ (for that point, it's good) and determine the coordinates of $(X - a)^{n} (X - b)^{n} \in \mathbb{R}_{2n}[X]$ in this basis.
My problem is about the last point, I tried to write the change of basis matrix, but it seems a little bit hard. Is there another way to proceed here ?

Thank your for your help.

Comment: Write $(X-a)^n(X-b)^n=(X-a)^n((X-a)+(a-b))^n$ and expand the second factor using the binomial formula.

Comment: So I have $(X - a)^{n} (X - b)^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} C_{n}^{k} (a - b)^{n - k} (X - a)^{n + k}$ ?

Comment: That's right. The coordinates are then $C_{n}^{k}(a-b)^{n-k}$. Assuming the notation $C_{n}^{k}$ is $n$ choose $k$, right?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you for your answer, I didn't think about writing $(X - b)^{n}$ like this (I never think about that kind of trick...).

Comment: I just noticed : it means that for every $k \in \{n + 1, ..., 2n\}$, we take the coordinate equals to $0$ right ?

Comment: No, the other way around. The powers that are present are $(X-a)^{n+k}$, which for $k=0,1,...,n$ are the powers $n,n+1,...,2n$. The coefficients that are zero are those of the powers $0,1,...,n-1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! Thank you again !